# Is there a way to setup Clicktale tag in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: web-analytics, web-analytics-tools, google-tag-manager

Since GTM doesn't support document.write() method the standard clicktale code doesn't work. Is there a workaround for this?

ClickTale employee has sent me these instructions:

```
Replace the document.write JS line above with the following: 
document.body.appendChild(externalScript);

Example:
<!-- ClickTale Bottom part --> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
var externalScript = document.createElement('script');
var scrSrc = document.location.protocol=='https:'?
'https://clicktalecdn.sslcs.cdngc.net/':
'http://cdn.clicktale.net/';

scrSrc += 'www11/ptc/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.js';

externalScript.src = scrSrc;
externalScript.type = 'text/javascript';
document.body.appendChild(externalScript);
</script> 
<!-- ClickTale end of Bottom part -->
```

I am not sure what to do with this. Has someone tried something like this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it is explained in http://wiki.clicktale.com/Article/Google_Tag_Manager_Integration

The procdeure is:

- Create a new container (or add the below to an existing container).
- Create a new Custom HTML tag in your GTM container.
- Copy and paste your project’s bottom code (from the ClickTale account) into the new
  tag.
- Check the “Support document.write” checkbox.

I tried it and it worked. Anyway I had to wait 24h (probably it's the time that Google needs for publishing the tag).

Answer (score 0):

The above answer will work, but Google Tag Manager does have a template for ClickTale now, I always try to refrain from using the Custom HTML tag because this can absolutely break your site if done incorrectly

**To set up ClickTale within GTM**

1. New - Tag
2. Certified Analytics
3. ClickTale Standard Tracking.